# Using connect with react-redux and redux-persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am getting the following error on my react-redux & redux-persist setup:

> The above error occurred in the component: in Connect(App) (created by
>   Route) in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(App))) in
>   withRouter(Connect(App)) in Router (created by BrowserRouter) in
>   BrowserRouter in PersistGate in Provider

I have it setup like this:

store.js

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import {persistStore,persistCombineReducers} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage' // default: localStorage if web, AsyncStorage if react-native

import { logger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import reducer from './reducers'

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger);

const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const reducers = persistCombineReducers(config, {reducer});

export const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, middleware);
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { persistor, store };
};
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './css/app.css';
import App from './containers/App';

import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react'
import configureStore from './store';
const { persistor, store } = configureStore()


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store} >
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
...
@withRouter
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: store.auth.isAuthenticated,
  };
})
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
...
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Full console log
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Is this the right way to declare the reducer? It works fine without redux-persist

authReducer.js

```
export default function reducer(state = {
  isAuthenticated: false
}, action) {
...
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

REHYDRATE console log
[image]

**UPDATE 4**

index.js (in reducers folder)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import user from './userReducer';
import auth from './authReducer';


export default combineReducers({
  user,
  auth
})
```

Comment: your app.js seems to be truncated or something..

Comment: I updated it, yet I think the issue is not in the missing code..

Comment: Maybe it specifies more details on the error in the console? There should the second message I suppose

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko added the full log

Comment: It looks like the auth reducer is missing the initial state?

Comment: you could set a breakpoint on after the store has been created and check what is store.getState().auth.. probably undefined

Comment: Added the authReducer.js code...is that the right way to declare it with redux-persist?

Comment: Undortunately I'm not a pro on redux-persist, but does the REHYDRATE action occurs and does it set the correct state?

Comment: I've found a long thread here on different issues https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/189

Comment: Thanks, I found a similar issue there...will give it a go. Updated the post with the log on the persist part

Comment: None of the suggestions worked.

Comment: Very distressing. But you know I'm just looking at the screenshot above, it's quite strange that the state has a key "reducer" which in it's turn has keys "auth" and others. How does it happen that way? It is redux-persist changes it to this shape?

Comment: obviously in such a case this selector `isAuthenticated: store.auth.isAuthenticated,` won't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162003/discussion-between-daniel-khoroshko-and-galgo).

Comment: CHeck out Update 4. This is how I had it set up for redux, really haven't touched anything here since before attempting to implement redux-perist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that one should not use both combineReducers and persistCombineReducers in one go. Similar situation could be found here https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/516